# Paho-MQTT subscribe to get a message from the topic

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, subscribe

I'm trying to implement a function publish_message in Python that uses the Paho MQTT library to publish and subscribe to MQTT messages. I have tried two ways of getting message from the topic. I'm doing it to check is the topic active(online).

1. First one is using on_message function, but I couldn't get the message outside of the on_message function. Value **received_message** is equal to None when I print it in **publish_message()** and I'm not sure how to fix it.
   Here is the code:

```
def publish_message():
    received_message = None

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        global received_message
        received_message = msg.payload.decode()
        client.disconnect()
        print(f"Received message on topic {msg.topic}: {msg.payload.decode()}")

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set("login", "password")
    client.connect("localhost", 1883)
    client.publish("test/checkOut", "STATUS")
    client.subscribe("test/checkIn")
    client.on_message = on_message
    print(received_message)
    client.loop_start()
```

2. Second solution is to use **subscribe.simple** and it works when topic is active, but when topic is off and I'm making a request I wait forever because **subscribe.simple** uses loop_forever(). How to stop it if topic is offline?

```
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribed
 def publish_message():
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set("login", "password")
    client.connect("localhost", 1883)
    client.loop_start()
    client.publish("test/checkOut", "STATUS")
    msg = subscribed.simple(f"{account}/checkIn",auth = {'username':"login", 'password':"pwd"})
    print(msg.payload.decode())
```

Thanks, in advance, for any suggestions.

Comment: What does "check is the topic active(online)" mean; do you consider it to be online if a message is received within a set period? My guess is that you want to connect and then wait for either a message or a time period to pass. Option 1 will not work because there will be a delay between subscribing and the message being received (so your `print(received_message)` runs before the variable is updated) . For option 2 you would need to add a timeout (perhaps using a modified version of [subscribe.simple](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py).